# Making Session Tokens More Random: ColdFusion 2018

Tags: variables, session, jakarta-ee, coldfusion

I've recently been tasked with mitigating issues from a ColdFusion 2018 Server vulnerability report. In particular, this one...

*Attack Type: SessionStrength
Session tokens that exhibit low entropy ("randomness") are often susceptible to prediction attacks. Insecure tokens can be due to inadequate pseudo-random
number generator, time-based values, static values, or values based on user attributes (username or user ID)...Session tokens should be created with a strong random number generator and gathered from a large pool of numbers. For example, an operating system's rand()
function can usually be sufficient if it can produce 32-bit values that are a statistically uniform distribution.*

And the recommendation is:

*Make sure that the Token values are at least 32 bits in size, especially for applications with large numbers of concurrent users and high amounts of daily page
requests.....*

My question is, how can I increase the randomness? The server uses J2EE session variables. Is there a way, perhaps on the Java side, that I can improve the randomness? Thank you.

Comment: Not sure about CF2018 because I’m on Lucee. But I thought (and the docs show) that Tomcats 8.0 default session id (jsession) generation is 16byte=128bit. Are you sure the information you‘ve gathered is correct?

Comment: Good question. I've been handed this task without a lot of context, so I'm (sort of) learning as I go. If you have it, can you post the Tomcat URL indicating the 128-bit length? Thank you.

Comment: Sure... https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/sessionidgenerator.html and search for 'sessionIdlength'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have either of these boxes checked in your ColdFusion Administrator?

[image]

Without this box checked, ColdFusion will not use a decent value for the CFToken. Instead it will use an incrementing 8-digit value. It's pretty poor default behavior.

Even if you do have it checked, it is possible that the incrementing behavior of the CFID (that is pair with the CFToken to determine a session) will raise a false flag with your vulnerability scanner. This is where the next checkbox can help.

[image]

With this box checked, you are telling ColdFusion to use a JEE session variable instead of the CF/CFToken combination. This will see a single session token that uses a good token. That should satisfy your vulnerability scanner.

I don't recall right off, if when the JEE checkmark is checked if it still writes the CFIF/CFToken cookies (despite the fact that it does not use them). If so, then your scanner may still flag it. If that happens, I believe you can use the following code (in your Application.cfc) to tell ColdFusion not to create those cookies.

```
this.setClientCookies = false;
```